# Dual os installation

Tags: ubuntu, operating-system

I have installed dual OS (Ubuntu) in my machine. The machine has 2GB RAM, and for the first few days, it was OK, but now machine is very slow.

I read that dual OS will affect the functioning of the machine.

Can you please help me, what will be reason for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The dual OS (not a Virtual Machine) Will not affect you RAM consumption as only one of them can be loaded at the same time.

If it's not a VM, but really a dual OS do you have enough space on your disk?

If it's almost full tt can slow down your PC. Especially if RAM is low to begin with.

Comment: No, its not full.

Is it because of any installation issue?

Comment: And that's a second distinct installation ? : you have to choose which OS to start when starting the PC. That's not a Virtual Machine?

Comment: Ours is dual installation and not virtual installation.

We will choose which OS to load while starting the machine.

Comment: Then It shall not affect the memory consumption. Are the **two** OS slower? If no is it the one recently installed?